# Did the Lord break His law by commanding Hosea to accept his adulterous wife?

Tags: law, hosea

Leviticus 20:10 NIV

> “‘If a man commits adultery with another man’s wife—with the wife of his neighbor—both the adulterer and **the adulteress are to be put to death**.

Hosea 3:1 NIV

> The Lord said to me, “Go, show your love to your wife again, **though she is loved by another man and is an adulteress.** Love her as the Lord loves the Israelites, though they turn to other gods and love the sacred raisin cakes.”

If Hosea's wife was a pardon case, please explain with scriptural support the principle of this pardon.

Comment: I think the question has answered itself by quoting Hosea 3:1. This was a sign, from God, via Hosea, to Israel in respect of their own spiritual adultery, that he was willing to forgive. Love is not the 'breaking' of law. Love is the fulfilling of law.

Comment: Divorce was _permitted_ in cases of adultery; it was never _required_.  It is not against the law to forgive and to renew the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

First point, punishment for adultery was to be carried out by the people of God; it was not a command that pagans roundabout the nation of Israel took as applying to them. (They had their own laws and punishments.) If an adulterer and an adulteress were not put to death in Israel, it was the leadership in Israel that had broken God's law - not God. So, **the short answer to your question is, "no".**

Second point, the case of Hosea was prophetic of God's dealings with his people who committed spiritual adultery against himself. One simply has to read the first chapter of Hosea to see that, and then to read the rest of it in light of God's own explanation as to the drama - the enactment - that would teach his people immense spiritual lessons, which are pertinent for all of God's people at all times, right to today. The point is also stated in the second chapter, God speaking of his spiritually adulterous people:

> "And I will betroth thee unto me for ever; yea, I will betroth thee in
> righteousness, and in judgment, and in lovingkindness, and in mercies.
> I will even betroth thee unto me in faithfulness; and thou shalt know
> the Lord... And I will have mercy upon her that had not obtained
> mercy; and I will say to them which were not my people, Thou art my
> people; and they shall say, Thou art my God." Hosea 2:19-23 A.V.

Of note is the fact that the apostle Paul quoted that last bit in Romans 9:22-33 along with other prophetic statements of God, about God's mercy extending also to non-Israelites.

There were other instances in the Old Testament where God commanded his prophets to enact scenes in front of Israel to teach them hard lessons, about the righteous judgment God was going to bring upon them for their spiritual adultery. Some enactments were quite shocking - designed to get the peoples' attention. This account of Hosea and his adulterous wife was in that tradition. Yet read God's further words as to the point of what he commanded Hosea to do:

> "Therefore have I hewed them by the prophets; I have slain them by the
> words of my mouth: and thy judgments are as the light that goeth
> forth. For I desired mercy, and not sacrifice; and the knowledge of
> God more than burnt offerings. But they like men have transgressed the
> covenant: there have they dealt treacherously against me." Hosea 6:5-7
> A.V.

It is, indeed, treachery against God to accuse him of any violation or injustice, when the accusers are guilty themselves of breaking God's covenant, especially when God is willing to forgive, and to show those violators love, and mercy. That is the point of what God commanded Hosea to do, and **all of that (briefly stated above) gives scriptural support regarding the pardon God may justly give.**

Comment: Your first sentence could imply that other nations didn't have laws against adultery.. they did. In Hammurabi's code, "The penalty for adultery is death by drowning; a husband, however, can pardon his wife, and if he does so the king may pardon her lover." I suspect that in practice a similar practice existed in Israel. Are there any instances in the Bible of people actually being executed for adultery?

Read more: http://www.historyworld.net/wrldhis/PlainTextHistories.asp?historyid=021#ixzz86Y374DCQ

Comment: @Dan Fefferman  Fair point; I have added an edit after that first sentence. Your last sentence (question) could make for a good one to answer on the Christianity site, but as it is not within the scope of the OPs Qs, all I will say is, read Numbers 25:1-18

Answer (score 0):

The fact that someone was believed guilty of a crime does not necessarily mean that the punishment had to be meted out.  There are many excellent examples of this in the Bible:

1. Hosea's wife, Gomer, was not stoned but forgiven as the OP's documents
2. Mary was (incorrectly) believed by Joseph to be guilty of fornication, but he had already decided not to press charges and NOT have her stoned according to the Torah law.
3. The woman caught in the act of adultery in John 8:1-11 was not executed
4. Tamar was technically guilty of adultery with Judah as recorded in Gen 38, but Judah was in no position to judge and forgave her.
5. David and Bathsheba were technically guilty of this adultery law but were never executed (2 Sam 11, 12)
6. ... many more ...

Indeed, there is no record of anyone ever being executed in the OT under this adultery law in Lev 20:10.  The reason may be quite simple - no one could be executed unless there were two or three witnesses (Deut 17:6, 19:15, see also Matt 18:16, Heb 10:28, etc); and that is the problem - adultery is usually a very private matter and in almost all cases, two or three witnesses to a private crime do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

God and Israel entered into a suzerain/vassal treaty. This type of treaty is one where there are two unequal parties, the powerful suzerain, and the vassal.

Here are the requirements of each party:

1. The suzerain promises to provide land and military protection.
2. The vassal agrees to be loyal to the suzerain and abide by the stipulations of the treaty
3. The suzerain enacts the blessings and curses stipulated in the treaty upon the vassal, depending on their obedience/disobedience.

In the treaty between God and Israel, God provides the promised land, and promises to lead them into battle (Deut 20:1).

He then outlines the blessings and curses, but through it all God:

1. Prioritises blessings over curses

> ...punishing the children for the sin of the parents to the **third and
> fourth generation** of those who hate me, 6 but showing love to **a
> thousand generations** of those who love me and keep my commandments. (Ex 24:4-6)

2. Is patient and merciful

> And he passed in front of Moses, proclaiming, “The Lord, the Lord, the
> compassionate and gracious God, slow to anger, abounding in love and
> faithfulness ... (Ex34:6)

3. Turns curses to blessings

> However, the Lord your God would not listen to Balaam but turned the
> curse into a blessing for you, because the Lord your God loves you.
> (Deut 23:5)

4. Restores blessings

> In the future, when you experience all these blessings and curses I
> have listed for you, and when you are living among the nations to
> which the Lord your God has exiled you, take to heart all these
> instructions. If at that time you and your children return to the
> Lord your God, and if you obey with all your heart and all your soul
> all the commands I have given you today, then the Lord your God will
> restore your fortunes. He will have mercy on you and gather you back
> from all the nations where he has scattered you. (Deut 30:1-3)

5. Increases blessings

> He will bring you to the land that belonged to your ancestors, and you
> will take possession of it. He will make you more prosperous and
> numerous than your ancestors. (Deut 30:5)

So when Gomer committed adultery, she broke her treaty with God. When God restored her he didn't break the Law (because as a suzerain it doesn't apply to him), instead he acted consistently within the blessings and curses he stipulated.

Answer (score 0):

> Matthew 9: The Pharisees saw this and said to his disciples, “Why does
> your teacher eat with tax collectors and sinners?” 12 He heard this
> and said, “Those who are well do not need a physician, but the sick
> do. 13 Go and learn the meaning of the words, ‘I desire mercy, not
> sacrifice.’...

Jesus was quoting from the prophet Hosea 6:6 when he told his detractors to "go and learn the meaning of the words." He knew that the Law was not as inflexible as it seemed to these particular Pharisees. The Law indeed commanded that both Hosea's wife and her lover be stoned, but Jesus knew that God's justice is tempered with mercy and love. In fact is: the Bible does not record any instance where adulterers were actually executed for their crime, despite several cases where the crime actually took place. In addition, Hosea's case was special, because God was using Hosea's couple as a model. As God forgave Israel and would take her back despite her unfaithfulness, so Hosea had to forgive Gomer and take her back as well.

**The OP requests: If Hosea's wife was a pardon case, please explain with scriptural support the principle of this pardon. The principle is that God desires mercy not sacrifice as both Jesus and the OT prophets indicated. God wanted to use Hosea's family as model exemplifying God's own mercy toward Israel, who had committed "spiritual adultery." In this case, mercy was more important than sacrificing Gomer's life in strict adherence to the Law.**